# How to use a colorbar to specify variation in data with respect to certain ranges

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have an AQI data for a specific region for PM 2.5
Now, I want to plot daily data for it and specifying color for different ranges of AQI data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('daily_44201_2019.csv')
df = df[['Date Local', 'AQI', 'State Name', 'County Name', 'City Name']]
df = df.iloc[0:152]
AQI_mean = df['AQI'].mean()
AQI = np.array(df['AQI'].tolist())
c = []
for i in range(0, len(AQI)):
    if AQI[i] < AQI_mean:
        c.append('red')
    else:
        c.append('green')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['Date Local'], df['AQI'], color=c)
plt.axhline(y=AQI_mean, color='black', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

After running the above code I got the error -

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: ['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', ...]
```

Following is the data -

Date Local   AQI State Name County Name City Name

0  2019-02-28  12.0    Alabama     Baldwin  Fairhope

1  2019-03-01  27.0    Alabama     Baldwin  Fairhope

2  2019-03-02  21.0    Alabama     Baldwin  Fairhope

3  2019-03-03  24.0    Alabama     Baldwin  Fairhope

4  2019-03-04  31.0    Alabama     Baldwin  Fairhope

Comment: try `c.append([1, 0, 0])` instead of `'red'` and `[0, 1, 0]` instead of `'green'`

Comment: It gave the same error as above `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0],...]`

Comment: oh also you need to use `plt.scatter` instead of `plt.plot`. It's possible that you need to use floats but I doubt it (i.e. `[1., 0., 0.]`)

Comment: Great. I posted a more efficient method for you to create that `c` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```py
c = []
for i in range(0, len(AQI)):
    if AQI[i] < AQI_mean:
        c.append('red')
    else:
        c.append('green')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['Date Local'], df['AQI'], color=c)
```

to use RGB triples and `scatter` instead of `plot`. Note you can use numpy to create the triples without needing a loop. This should be more efficient.

```
c = np.zeros((len(AQI), 3)
c[:, 0] = (AQI < AQI_mean).astype(int)
c[:, 1] = 1 - c[:, 0]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['Date Local'], df['AQI'], color=c)
```